# Flyway 4.0.3., spring boot 1.4 and baseline

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I set up boot with flyway:

```
flyway.baseline-version=2.7.0
flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
```

I have 2 sql files in db/migrate: V__2.7.0_base.sql and V__2.8.0_jobs.sql.

When I start the app it fails, because it tries to exec V__2.7.0_base.sql again...

mvn:flyway:info

```
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
| Version | Description           | Installed on        | State   |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 2.7.0   | << Flyway Baseline >> | 2016-08-09 12:25:04 | Baselin |
|         | 2.7.0 base            |                     | Pending |
|         | 2.8.0 jobs            |                     | Pending |
+---------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Why is 2.7.0 base pending? I set it as baseline - so it should be ignored?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, looking into the sourcecode I found out, that the file naming schema must be like V2_7_0__base.sql.
No idea why there are so many examples out there with naming schema like V__2.7.0_base.sql...

Comment: Which examples? I can *only* find examples with the prescribed scheme. See [How To](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how), [First Steps with Maven](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/maven), [Versioned Migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/versioned) and [SQL Migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql) documentation!